# Remove duplicated data in news file

Tags: php, regex

We have some data of news posting's in the following format. The `\t` is an actual tab character here.

```
Headline\tDate\tNews
```

The problem is in the past there were some issues with duplicated or extra fields like this..

```
Government Shutdown Latest News {null}{10/15/2013}  {10/15/2013}    words words words.
Email Flow in Exchange  {null}{10/17/2013}  {10/17/2013}    words words words....
Should This be banned?  {null}{10/23/2013}  {10/23/2013}    words words words....
```

I need to remove the **1st** bracket field which is `{null}` and the **3rd** duplicate field **along with the tab character that follows the  3rd field**.

So originally each line of this data should look like this.

```
Government Shutdown Latest News    {10/15/2013}    words words words....
Email Flow in Exchange    {10/17/2013}    {10/17/2013}    words words words....
Should This be banned?    {10/23/2013}    {10/23/2013}    words words words....
```

I am having trouble removing only these two fields and the tab though. It's matching them all.

```
preg_replace('/\{.*?\}(?={)|\{.*?\}\t/', '', $text);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **Negative Lookbehind** for the job.

```
(?<![^\s]){[^}]*}\t?
```

Regular expression:

```
(?<!           look behind to see if there is not:
 [^\s]         any character except: whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
)              end of look-behind
{              '{'
 [^}]*         any character except: '}' (0 or more times)
}              '}'
\t?            '\t' (tab) (optional)
```

**Note:** You could do this without escaping the `{ }` here.

See [working demo](https://eval.in/56996) for this and the [regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/dB9qS7)

Comment: Good answer, this works most of the time. But at times dont match other line breaks?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this pattern:

```
$result = preg_replace('~[^\s}]\s*\K{null}|{[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}}\t(?!\s*[^{])~', '', $text);
```

Comment: The only issue i run into is if the null field has a different value, can i change that to match any value?

Comment: @paulie.jvenuez: Yes, you can replace `null` by `[^}]*`